# How do I prove that a certain sequence has a convergent subsequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, convergence-divergence

so I have been having trouble with this question for a long time. I looked over the theorems so many times, but still can't think of anything.

Question:

Let (an) be a sequence of real numbers contained in the interval [c, d]. Show that (an) has a convergent subsequence.

Comment: Look at Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem

Comment: ohhhhh thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is essentially the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem, which states that every bounded sequence in $\mathbb{R^n}$ has a convergent subsequence.

In your case, you're interested in the existence of a convergent subsequence of a sequence {$a_n$} in $[a,b]$.Since the interval is bounded, any sequence {$a_n$} in $[a,b]$ is also bounded. By the theorem stated above, there exists a convergent subsequence of {$a_n$}.More specifically, there exists a convergent subsequence of {$a_n$} that converges to a point in $[a,b]$ since it's closed.